# Finding all tables having not null constraints in mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints

How to find all the table and column names that have not null constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you have an access to `information_schema` database, you can use this query:

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE
`IS_NULLABLE` = 'No'
AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'Your database name goes here'
```

Tested in MySQL 5.1